# Metatemplating in Nunjucks

Tags: nunjucks

I'm working on a Marionette app that has certain repeating UI patterns in Nunjucks, for example:

```
<div class="custom-input-group">
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username" required value="{{ username }}">
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Username</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-input-group">
    <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" required value="{{ first_name }}">
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>First Name</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-input-group">
    <input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" required value="{{ last_name }}">
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Last Name</label>
</div>
```

I'd like to abstract that into either a `macro` or a partial template, like so:

```
{% macro field(name, label='', type='text') %}
    <div class="custom-input-group">
        <input name="{{ name }}" type="{{ type }}" id="{{ name }}" required value={{ name }}>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>{{ label }}</label>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

So that I can use it like so:

```
{{ field('username', 'Username') }}
{{ field('first_name', 'First Name') }}
{{ field('last_name', 'Last Name') }}
```

However, this generates `value="username"` instead of `value="{{ username }}"`. How can I produce the latter?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I got it. Instead of trying to output another template, I have to pass in the final value to the macro itself, like this:

```
{% macro field(value, name, label='', type='text') %}
    <div class="custom-input-group">
        <input name="{{ name }}" type="{{ type }}" id="{{ name }}" required value={{ value }}>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>{{ label }}</label>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

And then use the macro like this:

```
{{ field(username, 'username, 'Username') }}
{{ field(first_name, 'first_name', 'First Name') }}
{{ field(last_name, 'last_name', 'Last Name') }}
```

This is still a little less DRY than I'd like, but heaps better than before.